# Problema con AsyncFileUpload de un WebForm - "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.resources" no encontrado

Tags: c#, asp.net

Esta pregunta fue creada inicialmente en [Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65394404/12511801):

---

Estoy trabajando en una solución en C# - ASP.NET - Framework 3.5.

Esta solución tiene un WebForm (*hijo de un `Site.master`*); este WebForm tiene múltiples `UpdatePanels`, [`TabContainer`](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/Tabs/Tabs.aspx) y (1) solo control de tipo [`AsyncFileUpload`](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx).

Localmente (*es decir, en mi máquina de desarrollo*), la página carga y procesa el archivo seleccionado correctamente, pero, esta página ha sido publicada en un equipo/servidor diferente y - cunado un archivo es seleccionado (*al usar el control `AsyncFileUpload`*), se muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
> the neutral culture.   Make sure
> "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly
> embedded or linked into assembly  "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile
> time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and
> fully signed.

En mi máquina, este error no ocurre se puede seleccionar y procesar el archivo según lo esperado (*sin errores de ningún tipo*).

---

Al buscar en internet las causas de este error, la mayoría de las sugerencias son:

- Añadir el control `ScriptManager` o `ToolkitScriptManager` - [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7161019/12511801). Al intentar esta opción (*al agregar cualquiera de los controles ScriptManager*), el WebForm carga en blanco (sin contenido) y en la ventana `output` - se muestra en runtime en Visual Studio 2012 - dice: `only a single ScriptManager can be added in the page` - lo cual es correcto, puesto que el Site.master ya tiene el control `ToolkitScriptManager`.
- Revisar si `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` está en la carpeta `bin`. Ya revisé y sí, la dll de AjaxcontrolToolkit está en la carpeta `bin`.

También he intentado:

- Revisar si las dlls `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` and `AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll` están en la carpeta `bin`. Efectivamente, las dlls mencionadas están en la ubicación mencionada.
- Cambiar `AsyncFileUpload` por `FileUpload`, pero, desde que esta página ya implementa múltiples `UpdatePanels`, el control `FileUpload` no funcionará por razones de seguridad - según mis pruebas y los resultados encontrados en Google (*por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109953/12511801)*).
- También he intentado usar solo el control `FileUpload` y la etiqueta `Triggers` para registrar el botón que enviaría el archivo seleccionado en el `FileUpload`, pero la página contiene múltiples `UpdatePanels` y cada vez que yo agrego la etiqueta `Trigger` y las sub-etiquetas `PostBackTrigger` o `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, haciendo que la página cargue vacía (`en blanco`) sin ninguna señal del error (*al haber añadido las etiquetas de trigger y relacionadas*). Por esta razón, me rendí y terminé usando el control `AsyncFileUpload`.

¿Qué más puede hacerse para revisar los recursos faltantes y/o la(s) causa(s) de este error y arreglar este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pude resolver el problema con el control *`AsyncFileUpload`*, pero, por otro lado, mientras buscaba cómo resolver este problema, intenté *de nuevo* cambiar el código para usar el control `FileUpload` - ubicado dentro del control `UpdatePanel` de AjaxControlToolkit.

Me encontré con [este post en social.msdn.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/cb409929-808d-4346-a1ca-7f227d9e14cf/fileupload-dentro-de-updatepanel?forum=netfxwebes) donde en la respuesta con más votos muestra otro enlace donde allí se explica cómo usar el control `FileUpload` que está dentro de un `UpdatePanel`.

El enlace es: [Using FileUpload Control inside ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel Control](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-FileUpload-Control-inside-ASP.Net-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Control.aspx)

Cambié mi código para que (*en lugar de usar el control **`AsyncFileUpload`***) usar el control **`FileUpload`** que está dentro del control **`UpdatePanel`**, pero, aquí está la ***trampa*** - así le digo (*porque me costó bastante tiempo resolver este tema, realmente*):

> Para seleccionar y enviar el archivo al lado servidor, el control
> **`Button`** o **`LinkButton`** - por ejemplo - que envía el archivo (*una vez seleccionado con el control **`FileUpload`***) debe tener su
> propio **`UpdatePanel`** con sus etiquetas respectivas - en este caso
> **`Triggers`** y **`PostbackTrigger`**.

---

*Ejemplo*:

En el .aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlbtnFileUploadDevols" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLoadClassFileDevoluciones" runat="server" Text="Cargar Archivo" 
            CssClass="chxbx" ForeColor="Teal" OnClick="BtnLoadChargeFileDevoluciones_Click" ValidationGroup="valChrgFileDevoluciones" CausesValidation="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLoadClassFileDevoluciones" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

En el aspx.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Cargar archivo.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">sender</param>
/// <param name="e">e</param>
protected void BtnLoadChargeFileDevoluciones_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (fupld_cargue.HasFile)
        {
            // Aquí, el archivo es detectado en el lado servidor  
            // y ha sido manejado según la lógica del programa.
        }
        else
        {
            // El archivo no se detectó en el lado servidor.
            MessageBox("Por favor, seleccione un archivo.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception handledException)
    {
        // Se omite el código de manejo de excepción en este ejemplo.
    }
}
```

Con la explicación anterior, finalmente pude resolver el problema que tenía al seleccionar un archivo usando **`FileUpload`** - el cual está dentro del **`UpdatePanel`**.